# How to properly define and document ! method for S4 class

Tags: r, devtools, r-s4, roxygen2

I am trying to define `!` method with for a custom S4 class. Let's say it looks like (`R/foo.R`)

```
#' Foo
#'
#' @param is_true logical
#' @export
setClass("Foo", slots = list(is_true = "logical"))

#' !
#'
#' Negates Foo
#'
#' @param x Foo
#'
#' @rdname !
#' @name !
#' @aliases !,Foo-method
#' @importFrom methods new
#' @examples
#' !new("Foo", is_true = FALSE)
#' @export
setMethod(
  "!", signature(x = "Foo"),
  function(x) { new("Foo", is_true = !x@is_true) }
)
```

`DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: foo
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.3)
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
Imports: methods
```

But when I run `devtools::check` I get:

```
Undocumented S4 methods:
  generic '!' and siglist 'Foo'
All user-level objects in a package (including S4 classes and methods)
should have documentation entries.
```

Can anyone explain what I am missing here?

Adjusting `@rdname`:

```
@rdname Foo
```

seems to partially address the problem but introduces another one:

```
* checking Rd files ... WARNING
prepare_Rd: Foo.Rd: \name should not contain !, | or @
```

what makes me think it is not the way to go, although generated `rd` files look fine.

Comment: You can probably just use a `"' @rdname` tag to override the default name value.

Comment: @Thomas `"' @rdname foo` was not enough, however `"' @name foo` removes the warning in my case.